# pyautogui not writing the Excel cell contents in text field

Tags: python-3.x, xlrd, pyautogui

I am trying to write data from Excel xlsx file in text fields of a software using pyautogui module. After running the code I open the software window to enter the data. Unfortunately the code does not write the data in the field. If I run this code for open notepad window, then it works.

```
""" Importing Pesticides list into Manabh Softwarer"""
import time
import xlrd
import pyautogui as gui

# Excel file location    
loc = ("D:\import.xlsx")

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) # Opens Sheet1 

time.sleep(10) # Delay to manually open Manabh data entry window
row = sheet.nrows+1
col = sheet.ncols
print('Columns:',col)
print('Rows:',row)

for i in range(1,row,1):
    j = 0
    val = sheet.cell_value(i, j)
    gui.write(val ,0.01 ) # Item name
    time.sleep(0.01)
    gui.press('tab')
    j += 1
    gui.write(sheet.cell_value(i, j),0.01 ) # Manufacturer
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Footnotes:

1. Windows 8.1 with adminstrative privileges.
2. 'Manabh Software' window running with adminstrative privileges.
3. [Here is link to Screenshot of 'Manabh Software Text Entry' window](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wqZ6MlBNizLwNLnKviIhtY3zEOzU1WTW/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution on a Reddit Forum where user was experiencing [similar problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/81uu08/hey_guys_i_need_some_help_because_pyautogui_is/) in a game.
The py file needs to run in elevated (Administrator) permission. 
I ran it by right clicking the IDLE shortcut in Start Menu and choosing 'Run as Administrator'. Then open the py file from file menu to run it by function key 'F5'.